# Defined Nelson-Siegel function not callable in Python

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy

I am trying to replicate the Nelson-Siegel (1987) model of the Yield Curve. I am new of Python (previously working in R) and I wrote the following function:

```
def nelson_siegel(tau, beta1, beta2, beta3, lambda1):
    return (
     beta1 + 
     beta2*(1-np.exp(-tau/lambda1))/(tau/lambda1) +
     beta3((1-np.exp(-tau/lambda1))/(tau/lambda1)-np.exp(-tau/lambda1))
     )
```

which I am going to optimize with `scipy.optimize.least_squares`.
However, even before going to the optimizitation I am not able to make this function callable and I do not get what it means. I just pass the parameters and I get either one of the following errors:

```
nelson_siegel(tau=10, beta1=0.5,beta2=0.3,beta3=0.1, lambda1=0.9)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

or

```
nelson_siegel(tau=1, beta1=5,beta2=3,beta3=10, lambda1=5)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def nelson_siegel(tau, beta1, beta2, beta3, lambda1):
    return (
     beta1 + 
     beta2*(1-np.exp(-tau/lambda1))/(tau/lambda1) +
     beta3 * ((1-np.exp(-tau/lambda1))/(tau/lambda1)-np.exp(-tau/lambda1))
     )
```

You haven't used `*` operator after beta3